# RestSharp: how to pass a variable to a function

Tags: c#, python, restsharp

I am using the RestSharp library for C#. I am using the POST method.

**Client C#**

```
        var client = new RestClient();
        client.BaseUrl = new Uri("http://localhost:5000");

        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

**Server Python**

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import MyIotHub

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])

def iot_message():

    message = "null"
    newHub = MyIotHub()

    newHub.send(message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

How can I use my iot_message function specifically? 
And how should I pass a variable to this function?

Comment: How are you exposing your webservice, is it in a RESTful way? Are you using web.py or another library? It would help if you posted your service code  as well so we know what you're pointing at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you call on your service is decided by the resource your request is set to i.e.

```
request.Resource = "your/endpoint/here"
```

Which in your case looks to be the root.

---

If you want to POST data to this endpoint, you can attach a parameter using

```
request.AddParameter("valuename", "value");
```

And access that on the form of your webservice by doing

```
def iot_message()
     whatever = request.form['valuename']
```

---

If you want that to be accessible from the URL instead, use

```
def iot_message()
    whatever = request.args.get('valuename')
```

And

```
request.AddParameter("valuename", "value", ParameterType.QueryString);
```

Comment: I don't understand how to specify the endpoint. The function name is not recognized. And request is not recognized by the web service.

Comment: On the service end, you can specify the endpoint using app.route. Have a look at http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#routing for more examples.

Make sure you're importing request before using it, with

   "from flask import request"

Comment: No problem, I find RestSharp to be a very useful library and I'm glad to help.